# Can I get configs outside strapi runtime?

Tags: knex.js, strapi

I'm implementing knex migrations on my api and I plan on running them on Heroku release phase (before the new version starts).

Is there any way I can get Strapi's parsed configs from my `knexfile.js`?

Something like this would be great:

```
const strapi = require('strapi');
strapi.config.database;
```

The problem is that I don't wanna duplicate my configs, and requiring the `config/environments/xxx/database.json` won't give me the "parsed" results. Meaning `"${process.env.DATABASE_HOST}"` won't be interpolated yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**

You can get Strapi's config this way:

```
const strapi = require('strapi')({ serveAdminPanel: false });

strapi.load()
  .then(() => {
    const config = strapi.config.currentEnvironment;
  });
```

But you can get Strapi's knex instance directly this way:

```
const strapi = require('strapi')({ serveAdminPanel: false });

strapi.load()
  .then(() => {
    const knex = strapi.connections[
      strapi.config.currentEnvironment.database.defaultConnection
    ];

    // do anything with knex here
    // like knex.migrate.latest();
  });
```

--

I tried to get the config first, but when I did I kept getting connection error so I managed to get the knex connection directly and things started working!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve that is to use `process.env` as opposed to using `strapi.config`. Strapi configs are no more than derived constants, so writing your own script won't bring overhead from launching strapi. I presume that you're using heroku environment variables. If variables are not available during the release phase (like Google App Engine gcp-build), you'll need to load those yourself using something like `dotenv` or `yenv`, or something I built: [kenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kenv) (object-base env loading).

I've had a similar issue with using strapi's bootstrap function - where i needed to execute my own migrations (outside of strapi land), so I ended up writing my own knex/bookshelf seed and migration scripts which were executed manually (not via a prerelease hook), prior to starting strapi.

On a separate note, [strapi hooks](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/hooks.html#hooks) may also be useful, if you want to build your migration scripts directly inside strapi.